# How to pass the result of an URL as a parameter?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I want be able to handle URLs like:

```
http://mywe/en/my-home/travels/search-results/age-min/18/
http://mywe/en/my-home/travels/search-results/age-min/18/age-max/50/
http://mywe/en/my-home/travels/search-results/town/acapulco
```

And so on, so it'll always follow this pattern

```
'([whatever until a slash]+/[whatever until a slash]+)+/$'
```

This would mean in regexp:

```
'([^/]+/[^/]+)+/$'
```

And in Django I'm trying this:

```
'^my-home/travels/search-results/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)/$'
```

This url works fine:

```
http://mywe/en/my-home/travels/search-results/testtesttest/
```

When I just replace `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]` by `[.]` (which should be "any character") it doesnt work. I'd like to know

- 1 - Why it doesnt work
- 2 - What is the regexp the "Django way" to do `'([^/]+/[^/]+)+/$'`

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use the regexp you correctly identify as the solution? There is no Django-specific way of doing regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question, the `'[.]'` doesn't work because it doesn't mean any character, it means dot. For any character you should use dot outside of `[]`.

For second question: you can define URL in similar way, but you can't catch all of matches for repeating group, it will only catch last one. That is limitation of regex.

But I have for you 2 possible solutions:

1. catch everything after search results to the end of your urlpattern in one capture group (`.*` for example) and parse that in your view to extract every possible value
2. Define more than one pattern in your URL pointing to that view. They can even have same name, for example:

   ```
   url(r'^/en/my-home/travels/search-results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$', your_view, name="your_url_name"),
   url(r'^/en/my-home/travels/search-results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$', your_view, name="your_url_name"),
   url(r'^/en/my-home/travels/search-results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$', your_view, name="your_url_name"),
   ```

   You can even help yourself with little loop:

   ```
   url(r'^/en/my-home/travels/search-results/', include([
       url('^' + '([^/]+)/([^/]+)/' * (i + 1) + '$', your_view, name="your_url_name"),
       for i in range(10) # how many maximum parameters you want to catch
   ]))
   ```